# Why is it "Tragödie um ihre Eltern" not "Tragödie von ihren Eltern"?

Tags: word-choice, preposition, style, grammaticality

> Nach der Tragödie um ihre Eltern kehrt das Glück zurück.
>
> After her parents' tragedy, her luck returned.

Why is *um* used instead of *von*? What if *von* is used not *um*, will it still be correct grammar?

Comment: Something else from what? As far as I understood this, the two sentences are not meaning the same, but this might be because my english is not as good as i want it to be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Um" is correct here. "Tragödie um" means a tragedy *about* something, which is what you want to say here.

The following sentence is grammatically also correct:

> Nach der Trägodie von ihren Eltern kehrt das Glück zurück.

However, this would probably be misunderstood as the parents being the source of the tragedy and not the victims.

Besides: Be careful about tense: While possible, the exact translation of the english sentence would read:

> Nach der Tragödie um ihre Eltern kehrte das Glück (zu ihr) zurück.

Comment: anstatt *"von ihren"* wird auch häufig *"ihrer"* verwendet

Comment: Nicht nur "häufig", sondern immer! Deshalb, nämlich, weil es korrekt ist, solange es den Genitiv noch gibt. Es ist ja auch "Vaters Hut" und nicht "der Hut vom Vater" oder "dem Vater sein Hut".